# Writing Regex with optional inputs

Tags: regex

I am using regexer.com to test my inputs. I have this regex with two groups. The first group matches 1 to 3 digits and is optional. The second group matches 2 to 3 digits and is mandatory.

`(\d{1,3})?[-]?(\d{2,3})`

```
 Group 1     Group 2
```

This regex works when I enter 123-456. It doesn't work when I enter an input without -. For example, input:123 -> group 1 gets 1 and group 2 gets 23. I want all the input without - to be in  group 2 because group 1 is optional.For input 1234, group 1 gets 123 and group 2 gets 4. How would I write a regex so that all my inputs without - would go to group 2 and if I enter an input without - greater than {2,3} it would not be accepted ?

Comment: If the string were `"1234"` is group 1 to be empty and group 2 to hold `"1234"` or should group 1 hold `"1"` and group 2 to hold `"234"` because group 2 must contain between 2 and 3 characters or something else?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to define your groups in the following way:

```
Group 1: 1-3 digits and a hyphen (-), all optional
Group 2: 2-3 digits, mandatory
```

Writing your regex this way will ensure that if you have a lone 2 or 3 digits, it will always be recognized as a part of group 2 since group 1 requires the hyphen to be recognized.

Example:

```
(\d{1,3}[-])?(\d{2,3})
```

Validated with regex101.com. Also, remember to anchor your regex as appropriate.

If you'd like it to track the beginning and end of the string, you can anchor your expression with ^ signifying the beginning, and $ signifying the end.

Example:

```
^(\d{1,3}[-])?(\d{2,3})$
```

Comment: btw, `[-]` can be simplified to just `-`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you may attempt to match the following regular expression.

```
^((?:(?=\d+\-)\d{1,3}|(?!\d+\-)\d{0,3}?))\-?((?:(?<=\-)\d{2,3}|(?<!\-)\d{2,3}))$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AS1g4H/1)

This regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
(?x)            # invoke free-spacing mode
^               # match the beginning of the string
(               # begin capture group 1
  (?:           # begin a non-capture group
    (?=\d+\-)   # pos lookahead asserts later in the string is a hyphen
    \d{1,3}     # match 1 to 3 digits, as many as possible
    |           # or
    (?!\d+\-)   # neg lookahead asserts no hyphen later in the string 
    \d{0,3}?    # match 0 to 3 digits, as few as possible
  )             # end of non-capture group
)               # end of capture group 1
\-?             # optionally match a hyphen
(               # begin capture group 2
  (?:           # begin a non-capture group
    (?<=\-)     # pos lookbehind asserts prev char is a hyphen
    \d{2,3}     # match 2 to 3 digits, as many as possible
    |           # or
    (?<!\-)     # neg lookbehind asserts prev char not a hyphen
    \d{2,3}     # match 2 to 3 digits, as many as possible
  )             # end of non-capture group
)               # end of capture group 2
$               # match end of string
```